# Save current page state javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, local-storage

Is it possible to save the current state of a webpage so you can later restore it to that state?

Through "state" I mean everything that defines the current behavior of the page: html tags, css, JavaScript variables, form data, etc...

So you could simply have something like: `savePage()` which stores all the needed data in localhost and then use `loadPage()` to retrieve that data.

I guess the `html`, `css` and `inputs value` are easy to save, but what about all the JavaScript variables on that page? Is it possible to save all the JavaScript variables held in the memory? (probably in a `JSON` object).

Comment: No, you save your own state

Comment: Why? Isn't it possible to get all the JavaScript variables in use by the current page? Aren't all bound to the `window` object?

Comment: No, many variables are hidden within closures and can't be accessed from the outside.

Answer (score 3):

Essentially what you want is  to resuse something when user comes back,so here is my answer.

well its certainly possible.You can traverse the dom and put your stuff in to localstorage.

LocalStorage supports only string.

Use localStorage if you want the data to persist beyond browser close and SessionStorage if i want the data to persist with in the browser close.

**NOTE**:IE7 + support for SessionStorage and LocalStorage

It has plenty of memory as compared to cookies(4kb with 15 to 20 cookies allowed per domain).

- IE(10 mb)
- Mozzilla(5 mb)
- Chrome(2.5 mb)

Answer (score 0):

Well depends, you can use [localStorage](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html) to do that on the client side, or for example write a javascript function to send all variables to the server and store them there.

You need to think more about that problem.

Comment: Yes, but I want it to be some-kind of a library, so I can use it on any website, simply execute `savePage()` so it automatically does that. I will post soon the code I have used in a game to automatically save all the instances in that game.