# Save and load entire web page state (Visual HTML, And javascript Variables)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, session, session-state

So lately I've been working on this project, which will end at the end of January (end of this week).

http://www.nikollr3.three.axc.nl/ (this is a preview of the program a few months ago, but u get an idea)

We have started testing the website and noticed that it was sometimes making Firefox crash.. since Firefox' error or crash reports were never of any use (no useful information found), I have no idea how to fix this error. And a possible solution would be to have a save / load button on the web page, which can save or load a state (and for example autosave state untill it crashes) then when it crashes you would be able to reload the last state and continue working on the project. By saving a 'state' I mean recreating the EXACT moment as to when the save button was clicked, thus same javascript variable values and same HTML looks.

I have found little things about this on the internet, the only one relevant being for android phones,.. Any ideas or implementations?

Answer (score 0):

write all your variables and "HTML looks" (attributs) to a XML-file.  load (`if (exist(XML)`pseudo-code) all necessary data onPageLoad

Comment: @Faarbhurtz sorry for that, but no reason for becoming impolite. Have a look at [this related post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18550385/save-current-page-state-javascript?rq=1), too.